# CMake linking error with multilevel src directory

Tags: cmake, linker-errors

I'm having issues linking my project together using cmake.
The project consists of a library, "mylib", and an executable, "mybin", which is linked with it. The structure is the following:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt 
├── include
│   ├── mylib.h
│   ├── entities
│   │   ├── entities.h
│   │   ├── entityA.h
│   │   └── entityB.h
│   └── shapes
│       ├── shapes.h
│       ├── shapeA.h
│       └── entityB.h
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── entities
    │   ├── entityA.cpp
    │   └── entityB.cpp
    └── shapes
        ├── shapeA.cpp
        └── entityB.cpp
```

Where mylib uses all .cpp and .h files (except from main.cpp) to create a static library, and mybin uses main.cpp and links with mylib.h. mylib.h pulls the other header files from the include directory.

Right now, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(myproject VERSION 1.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(mylib
    src/entities/entityA.cpp
    src/entities/entityB.cpp

    src/shapes/shapeA.cpp
    src/shapes/shapeB.cpp

    include/mylib.h

    include/entities/entities.h
    include/entities/entitiesA.h
    include/entities/entitiesB.h

    include/shapes/shapes.h
    include/shapes/shapeA.h
    include/shapes/shapeB.h
)

target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC include)

target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC)

target_compile_features(mylib PRIVATE cxx_std_11)

add_executable(mybin src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mybin PRIVATE mylib)

target_compile_features(mybin PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

When I try to build my code, with

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

The library builds fine, but I get linking errors while the executable is building:

```
/usr/bin/ld: shapeA.cpp:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `MyLib::Entities::EntityA::normalize_inplace()'
```

Not sure how to fix this, I tried to follow numeral tutorials and looking at other issues here and examples, but couldn't get to fix it. The actual code is in [my github](https://github.com/guillaumetousignant/another_path_tracer), in the "cmake" branch.

Thank you very much.

EDIT

The linking error I copied above is used in the src/shapes/shapeA.cpp file:

```
#include "shapes/shapeA.h"
#include <algorithm>

using MyLib::Entities::EntityA;

Mylib::Shapes::ShapeA::ShapeA() {}

Mylib::Shapes::ShapeA::~ShapeA(){}

bool Mylib::Shapes::ShapeA::intersect(const EntityA &entity) const {
    const EntityA invdir = (EntityA(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) + entity).normalize_inplace();

    return true;
}
```

It is defined in src/entities/entityA.cpp :

```
#include "entities/EntityA.h"

using MyLib::Entities::EntityA;

EntityA::EntityA(double a, double b, double c) : 
    a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) {}

EntityA::~EntityA(){}

EntityA EntityA::normalize_inplace(){
    const double tot = std::sqrt(a_*a_ + b_*b_ + c_*c_);
    a_ /= tot;
    b_ /= tot;
    c_ /= tot;

    return EntityA(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

EntityA EntityA::operator+(EntityA other) {
    return EntiryA(a_ + other.a_, b_ + other.b_, c_ + other.c_);
}
```

There are many more linking errors like that one, I think nothing gets linked correctly at all.
Also, I used a makefile previously and all linking was being made correctly.

Comment: Which **source** file **defines** missed method `(MyLib::Entities::EntityA::normalize_inplace`)? Show that definition (add it to the question post).

Comment: I added an example file where the error appears, but it seems to appear for all objects.

Comment: Ok, the last file actually defines the method. How is this file named? Where (at which line) do you compile it in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Note, that according to its signature, the method should return `EntityA` object, but actually it doesn't return anything. A compiler should warn about that.

Comment: I added the filename, I had switched them. It is at the second line after add_library. Oops, I removed the return when I shortened the function when pasting it. I do return something, and when compiling with a makefile I get no warnings and everything works.

Comment: Well, I have no more guesses what could be wrong: everything you show in the question post looks reasonable. Could you prepare [mcve] which reproducing your problem? Such a way we could run that code on our machines, get your error and trying to find out what actually goes wrong.

Comment: The minimal reproductible example thing worked! It was a silly mistake after all, I had one  "src/shapes/shapeB.cpp"-like line missing in my CMakeLists.txt. Thank you for your help!